# Alamofire doesn't execute whole code in response closure

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get photos of user. On the TableView of friends list I call the function

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        guard segue.identifier == "showFriendSegue" else {return}
        guard let showFriend = segue.destination as? FriendCollectionViewController else {return}
        let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let userKey = usersSectionTitles[indexPath!.section]
        if let userValues = usersDictionary[userKey] {
            let user = userValues[indexPath!.row]
            let id  = userValues[indexPath!.row].id
            showFriend.friend.append(user)
            showFriend.friendImages = Photo.photo.getUserPhotos(id: id)
        }
    }
```

```
func getUserPhotos(id: Int) -> [String]{
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get")!
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "owner_id" : id,
            "album_id" : "profile",
            "rev" : 1,
            "access_token" : Session.session.token,
            "v": Session.session.APIVersion
        ]
        
        var userPhotos: [String] = []
    
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
              
                let photosArray = json["response"]["items"].arrayValue

                for sizes in photosArray {
                    let onlyOneType = sizes["sizes"].arrayValue.filter({$0["type"] == "z"})
                    for url in onlyOneType {
                        userPhotos.append(url["url"].stringValue)
                    }
                }

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
        return userPhotos
    }
```

It seems for me like Alamofire doesn't have enough time to make whole code and it's strange because I expect that code should be executed consistently.
When I check code with breakpoints I see that AF.request starts, then right away return userPhotos executes, photosArray is not empty but on the friend's page I have an empty array of photos.
How should I fill the array from AF? I thought it was obvious and simple thing but I can't understand what's wrong with this closure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alamofire request runs asynchronously, that's why your code returns empty `userPhotos` at once. You need to use completion handler for this function. It will be called when your request returns a response with ids.

And I recommend to call this function in the `FriendCollectionViewController` instead of `func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?)`.

Attach code snippet below how to use completion for your case.

```
func getUserPhotos(id: Int, completion: @escaping (Result<[String], Error>) -> Void) {
        let url = URL(string: "https://api.vk.com/method/photos.get")!
        let parameters: Parameters = [
            "owner_id" : id,
            "album_id" : "profile",
            "rev" : 1,
            "access_token" : Session.session.token,
            "v": Session.session.APIVersion
        ]
        AF.request(url, method: .get, parameters: parameters, headers: nil).responseJSON { (response) in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let value):
                let json = JSON(value)
              
                let photosArray = json["response"]["items"].arrayValue
                var userPhotos: [String] = []
                for sizes in photosArray {
                    let onlyOneType = sizes["sizes"].arrayValue.filter({$0["type"] == "z"})
                    for url in onlyOneType {
                        userPhotos.append(url["url"].stringValue)
                    }
                }
                completion(.success(userPhotos))

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can call your method.

```
Photo.photo.getUserPhotos(id: friend[0].id, completion: { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let ids):
      // handle your ids here
    case .failure:(let error):
      // handle error
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But how should I call this? Now function requars comletition field, what do I have to write there? I'm trying  friendImages = Photo.photo.getUserPhotos(id: friend[0].id)

Comment: Sorry for bothering, but I guess I'm stupid af. On FriendController I have an empty Array: FriendPhotos.  In DidLoad I call my method and in block .success I say FriendsPhotos = ids. Then in DidLoad again, I check if my array is empty with "if ...". But when I tap on my friend, this checking says my array is empty and only then block .succes executes

Comment: Can you please share code of your view controller to see what’s going wrong in your flow. If you try to check is array empty on the next line after you call method to get identifiers, it always be empty, cause your request need some time to get a response, that’s why you call it asynchronously to prevent blocking an user experience while waiting for API response.

Comment: override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
Photo.photo.getUserPhotos(id: friend[0].id, completion: { result in
   switch result {
   case .success(let ids):
             self.friendImages = ids
            case .failure(let error):
              print(error)
            }
        })
        if friendImages.isEmpty {
            friendImages = ["https://vk.com/images/camera_400.png"]
            nameOfImageThatIsShown = friendImages[0]
        } else {
            nameOfImageThatIsShown = friendImages[0]
        }
        quantityOfUserImages = friendImages.count

Comment: It looks awful. I'm first time here, how can I share my code more readable?

Comment: You should write this conditions inside completion in the`.success` case, cause in that place you have a response from the API.

Comment: I've tried, but in this case "func collectionView" executes faster anyway and on the place where should be url of photo is nil

Comment: @Webunreal obviously that `cellForRow` method runs faster, you can show progress indicator while fetching data and in your completion hide loader and reload data for your collection view.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really helped me